# Nome di un poligono con un numero qualsiasi di lati

Tags: word-choice, translation, single-words, nouns, mathematics

Come si dice in italiano "n-gon", un poligono con n (o addirittura un numero imprecisato di lati)?

Grazie.

Comment: Poligono, see here for a complete list: https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poligono#Nomi_di_poligono

Comment: Potresti dire *n*-gono (pronunciandolo “ennagono”), ma ti capirebbero in pochi.

Comment: @DaG: pronunciato "enneagono" o "ennegono"? In spagnolo un "eneágono", in catalano un "enneàgon" o in francese un "ennéagone" è un poligono di 9 lati (cioè, un "ennagono" in italiano).

Comment: Hai ragione, @Charo, l'“ennagono” è il poligono con nove lati, ma sono abbastanza certo di aver sentito chiamare così anche il *n*-gono, magari sottolineando la presenza della *n* (qualcosa come “enn(e)-agono”). Ma comunque non è un nome ufficiale; presumibilmente i matematici in città o università diverse lo diranno in modo un po' diverso, se pure lo dicono.

Comment: Quindi enne-agono, per distinguerlo da ennagono (9 lati), oppure semplicemente poligono, che mi da si riferisce alla stessa cosa, senza enfatizzare il fatto che il numero di lati può variare ed è un numero generico.

Answer (score 4):

Nel parlato, "enne-agono" è forse un po' colloquiale ma in uso tra i matematici, almeno quelli che ho frequentato io, e credo che sia compreso un po' ovunque (così come "kappa-agono", o "dueenne-agono", o qualunque altra espressione al posto della n). Se devi scriverlo in un libro, "$n$-agono" oppure "poligono con $n$ lati" secondo me vanno bene entrambi. (I dollari sono sintassi LaTeX -- se invece stai scrivendo un libro di matematica in Word, beh, tanti auguri.) :)

Comment: Veramente è sintassi TeX, non necessariamente LaTeX.

Comment: Secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/enneagono/) però un "enneagono" è un poligono con 9 lati.

Comment: @Charo Vero, ma se stai scrivendo un libro di matematica con TeX, beh, tanti auguri comunque. :)

Comment: Non sto scrivendo nessun libro, ma a volte scrivo appunti o esercizi per i miei allievi in TeX. Uso i macro che ha scritto un'altra persona, però: non sono mica un'esperta di TeX. Immagino che dal contesto si possa capire se si sta parlando di un poligono con $n$ lati oppure con 9 lati. E nel caso di una possibile ambiguità sempre si può dire "poligono con $n$ lati".

Comment: `$n$\nobreakdash-agono`, naturalmente (occorre `amsmath`).